# How to reference a subdirectory in a batch file of which path depends on user account?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file with below command which I have to share with my team members. In the command below `C:\Users\a514502` is part of the directory path and is dynamic depending on user account.

How do I get this and pass it to command below so that my team members do not have to change the path manually in the file?

I understand variables can be used to get to the path and then pass it, but I could not get it working.

```
-report "C:\Users\a514502\parasoft\Auto_Results" -environmentConfig "C:\Users\a514502\parasoft\prod.env"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%USERPROFILE%` which references environment variable **USERPROFILE** containing path to profile directory of currently used user account on Windows, i.e. `C:\Users\a514502` in your case.

For a list of environment variables defined by Windows for each user account and including the system variables see the Wikipedia article about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

Answer (score 0):

You should run the command "set|more" to see what environment variables you can work with like these two:

```
-report "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\parasoft\Auto_Results" -environmentConfig "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\parasoft\prod.env"
```

Answer (score 0):

`%USERPROFILE%` worked for me and `Set|More` helped me to understand environment variables. Thanks a lot.